# Laravel отношения, кастомное значение

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть две таблицы
users
chat_messages

У user поле id с значением int - 1
У chat_messages поле room с значением - room_user_1

как в отношении указать кастомное значение, чтоб из связать?

По типу 'room_user_'.$user_id

Comment: Скорее всего никак. Это не вопрос к Laravel Eloquent даже, а к чистому SQL. Есть id и PK, который связан через id. Если у Вас связь `room_user_1`, то и id должен быть такой же. Вообще зачем Вы так портите себе таблицы?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar да дело в том, что эта таблица не только для чатов пользователей... частично решил проблему через CONCAT() и ленивые загрузки, но вылезла проблема пагинации коллекции. Вобщем плюнул и добавил еще одно поле, с нормальной связью =)

Comment: Я просто не могу понять, в какой ситуации такое вообще может понадобиться...

Comment: Если доходит до таких безумных связей, значит в построении логики что то пошло не так. Это из личного опыта - ни разу не подводило. Надо остановиться и еще раз подумать.